# Method 'Range' of object_Worksheet failed error -2147417848 (80010108)

Tags: excel, vba

I've googled extensively, but can't seem to find anything on my problem. I have a workbook that has various VBA intermingled with in cell formulas. As it sits now it works fine, but if I try and add or modify a simple cell reference such as "=N24" it breaks my code and throws up the error:

> Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

This happens whether I'm referencing a calculated cell, a user filled cell, or a blank cell.

Here's the sheet calculate code, which is the only code on this particular sheet. I know it's rudimentary, but usually simple is good. When it throws this error, it breaks at:

```
Sheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").ClearContents
```

If I remove that code, then it breaks at the first IF statement line.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim SIZE As String
Dim THICKNESS As Single
Dim WIDTH As Single
Dim HEIGHT As Single
Dim WALL As Single
Dim WALL1 As String
Dim OD As Single
Dim FINALROW As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Sheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").ClearContents
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("E4") = "STRUCTURAL_I_BEAM" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4") <> 0 Then
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("IBEAM").Range("Q2:Q100").ClearContents
SIZE = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4").Value
FINALROW = Sheets("IBEAM").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To FINALROW
        If Worksheets("IBEAM").Cells(i, 2) = SIZE Then
            Worksheets("IBEAM").Cells(i, 8).Copy
            Sheets("IBEAM").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
    Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").Value = Worksheets("IBEAM").Range("Q2").Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If


If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("E4") = "STRUCTURAL_CHANNEL" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4") <> 0 Then
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("CHANNEL").Range("Q2:Q100").ClearContents
SIZE = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4").Value
FINALROW = Sheets("CHANNEL").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To FINALROW
        If Worksheets("CHANNEL").Cells(i, 2) = SIZE Then
            Worksheets("CHANNEL").Cells(i, 6).Copy
            Sheets("CHANNEL").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
    Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").Value = Worksheets("CHANNEL").Range("Q2").Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If


If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("E4") = "STRUCTURAL_ANGLE" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4") <> 0 Then


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("ANGLE").Range("Q2:Q100").ClearContents
WIDTH = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4").Value
HEIGHT = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("G4").Value
THICKNESS = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("H4").Value
FINALROW = Sheets("ANGLE").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To FINALROW
        If Worksheets("ANGLE").Cells(i, 3) = WIDTH And Worksheets("ANGLE").Cells(i, 4) = HEIGHT And Worksheets("ANGLE").Cells(i, 6) = THICKNESS Then
            Worksheets("ANGLE").Cells(i, 7).Copy
            Sheets("ANGLE").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
    Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").Value = Worksheets("ANGLE").Range("Q2").Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If


If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("E4") = "TUBE_RECTANGLE" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4") <> 0 Then


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("RECTTUBE").Range("Q2:Q100").ClearContents
WIDTH = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4").Value
HEIGHT = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("G4").Value
WALL = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("H4").Value
FINALROW = Sheets("RECTTUBE").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To FINALROW
        If Worksheets("RECTTUBE").Cells(i, 3) = WIDTH And Worksheets("RECTTUBE").Cells(i, 4) = HEIGHT And Worksheets("RECTTUBE").Cells(i, 5) = WALL Then
            Worksheets("RECTTUBE").Cells(i, 6).Copy
            Sheets("RECTTUBE").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
    Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").Value = Worksheets("RECTTUBE").Range("Q2").Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If


If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("E4") = "TUBE_SQUARE" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4") <> 0 Then


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("SQUARETUBE").Range("Q2:Q100").ClearContents
WIDTH = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4").Value
WALL = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("H4").Value
FINALROW = Sheets("SQUARETUBE").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To FINALROW
        If Worksheets("SQUARETUBE").Cells(i, 3) = WIDTH And Worksheets("SQUARETUBE").Cells(i, 5) = WALL Then
            Worksheets("SQUARETUBE").Cells(i, 6).Copy
            Sheets("SQUARETUBE").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
    Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").Value = Worksheets("SQUARETUBE").Range("Q2").Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If


If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("E4") = "TUBE_ROUND" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4") <> 0 Then


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("ROUNDTUBE").Range("Q2:Q100").ClearContents
OD = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4").Value
WALL1 = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("H4").Value
FINALROW = Sheets("ROUNDTUBE").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To FINALROW
        If Worksheets("ROUNDTUBE").Cells(i, 3) = OD And Worksheets("ROUNDTUBE").Cells(i, 4) = WALL1 Then
            Worksheets("ROUNDTUBE").Cells(i, 5).Copy
            Sheets("ROUNDTUBE").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
    Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").Value = Worksheets("ROUNDTUBE").Range("Q2").Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If


If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("E4") = "PIPE" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4") <> 0 Then


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("PIPE").Range("Q2:Q100").ClearContents
OD = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4").Value
WALL1 = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("H4").Value
FINALROW = Sheets("PIPE").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To FINALROW
        If Worksheets("PIPE").Cells(i, 3) = OD And Worksheets("PIPE").Cells(i, 4) = WALL1 Then
            Worksheets("PIPE").Cells(i, 5).Copy
            Sheets("PIPE").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
    Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").Value = Worksheets("PIPE").Range("Q2").Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If


If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("E4") = "SOLID_ROUND" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4") <> 0 Then


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("ROUND").Range("Q2:Q100").ClearContents
OD = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4").Value
FINALROW = Sheets("ROUND").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To FINALROW
        If Worksheets("ROUND").Cells(i, 3) = OD Then
            Worksheets("ROUND").Cells(i, 4).Copy
            Sheets("ROUND").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
    Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").Value = Worksheets("ROUND").Range("Q2").Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If


If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("E4") = "SOLID_FLAT" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4") <> 0 Then


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("FLAT").Range("Q2:Q100").ClearContents
THICKNESS = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4").Value
WIDTH = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("G4").Value
FINALROW = Sheets("FLAT").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To FINALROW
        If Worksheets("FLAT").Cells(i, 3) = THICKNESS And Worksheets("FLAT").Cells(i, 4) = WIDTH Then
            Worksheets("FLAT").Cells(i, 5).Copy
            Sheets("FLAT").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
    Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").Value = Worksheets("FLAT").Range("Q2").Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If


If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("E4") = "SOLID_SQUARE" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4") <> 0 Then


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("SQUARE").Range("Q2:Q100").ClearContents
WIDTH = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4").Value
FINALROW = Sheets("SQUARE").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To FINALROW
        If Worksheets("SQUARE").Cells(i, 3) = WIDTH Then
            Worksheets("SQUARE").Cells(i, 4).Copy
            Sheets("SQUARE").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
    Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").Value = Worksheets("SQUARE").Range("Q2").Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If


If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("E4") = "SOLID_HEX" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4") <> 0 Then


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("HEX").Range("Q2:Q100").ClearContents
WIDTH = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("F4").Value
FINALROW = Sheets("HEX").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To FINALROW
        If Worksheets("HEX").Cells(i, 3) = WIDTH Then
            Worksheets("HEX").Cells(i, 4).Copy
            Sheets("HEX").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
    Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").Value = Worksheets("HEX").Range("Q2").Value
    Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N25").Value = Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N8").Value / 12 * Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").Value
    Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N26").Value = Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N25").Value - ((Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N6").Value * Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N10").Value / 12) * Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").Value)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Seems an odd error, just as an initial check can you preface the Sheets line with ThisWorkbook and change sheets to worksheets ? so ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CALCULATIONS"). Also can you verify that the workbook will always contain a sheet called "SHEET1"?

Comment: I tried that initially, to no avail.  I probably should have said as much in my initial question.  Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Excel is Busy calculating the cells, you are trying to delete/change the cell, invoking another calculation event. Hence blocking the cell/range access. Same will happen you had a mix of chart sheets with normal sheets.

Just disable the events before making any change/delete and once done re-enable events.

```
...............
Dim i As Integer
Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").ClearContents
.........Your Code....
.....................
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Another alternative is to wait till CalculationState is `xlDone` but if you too many lengthy calculation, this might crash your application.

Comment: I have added the code as suggested, and so far this seems to be holding.  Thanks for the rapid response!

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can not put reference on Range("N24") because you will get an infinite loop.

The first line of your code is proof for that:

```
Sheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").ClearContents
```

Why, because you put reference of Range("N24") and click ENTER you get fired Change event, than your line for ClearContents erase content and after that you got calculation in your cell with this reference and here we go again fired Change Event because of that. And so on and so on (an infinite loop).

At your place I tried to do the following.

For example edit this line of code:

```
Sheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").ClearContents
```

with this

```
If Sheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24") <> "" Then
    Sheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("N24").ClearContents
End If
```

End every part of code with ClearContents edit like above example.

This would ensure the non-appearance of infinite loop.

Comment: I tried this change as suggested, and it threw the same error.  The =N24 was just a (poor) example.  It happens when I try and enter anything that would trigger a calculation.  So far cyboashu's suggestion seems to be holding.  Thanks for the rapid response!